# Android Layouts Not Working After Update

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've been away from my project a for a few weeks. I came back to it today, updated Android Studio, the SDK, dependencies etc and after my first run I'm getting these strange errors on my layouts.

Some pictures below:

[image: Print 1]

[image: Print 2]

It's happening on an emulator running API 19. I don't get it on another emulator running API 23, or on my Nexus 6P running 6.0.1. I tried rolling back to an older commit (though I've made no changes apart from updating AS since my last commit a few weeks ago) and I still get the problem.

It looks more like a bug to me than anything wrong with code or settings, I can't really understand why anything would show up like that. I'm having trouble even Googling for help, because I wouldn't even know how to describe the problem without pictures.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe something related to the support library... which dependencies have been updated?

Comment: I reverted the dependencies back to what they were before I updated, and I still get the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like you use AppCompat elements instead of Holo or what ur used before. What is your target sdk? Thy cahnge it to 22 and make shure that your application style is extendet from non Apcompat. For future: it will be better change your style for elements which corupts

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you double check the versions of your gradle dependencies: Android Support Library and Android design support library.

You can define specific versions for your dependencies instead of using the most recent, like this:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Also you can test them on Android virtual devices rather than Genymotion and see the results.

Check your res-values directories for styles and dimension resources, you may find something specific to API level 19 (res/values-v19) that causes this behavior.

Comment: I reverted them to known-working old version and am still getting the problem.

Regarding using Android Virtual Devices, that's another issue. I enabled virtualization in my bios but it's still not letting me run the emulator.

Comment: Maybe you can check if there are specific resources for API level 19, please check the updated answer. also did you try running on AVD?

Comment: The pictures in the question show Genymotion being used

Comment: Ran it on an API 19 AVD and yeah, still getting the same problem.

Comment: Also on anything pre-19.